# Combine three fields into one

Tags: sql, ms-access, sql-update

I am trying to make a change to one of the tables in our database named `NonConf`.  Currently, we have three ***Yes/No*** fields called `Closed`, `Open`, and `OnHold`.  We are going to be adding more statuses and I think it is a bad idea to continue adding fields for the new statuses.  Instead I would like to convert the fields to one `Status` field.

I have already added the `Status` field to the `NonConf` table.  How do I use an ***UPDATE*** query to populate `Status`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use a [Switch](http://office.microsoft.com/en-us/access-help/switch-function-HA001228918.aspx) expression instead of nesting multiple `IIf` expressions.

```sql
UPDATE NonConf AS N
SET N.Status = 
    Switch
        (
            N.Closed, "Closed", 
            N.Open, "Open",
            N.OnHold,"OnHold",
            True, ""
        );
```

`Switch` operates similar to `SELECT CASE` in VBA.  So it returns the value from the first expression/value pair where the expression is `True`.  The last expression/value pair (`True, ""`) catches anything which falls through the earlier pairs.  Perhaps instead of an empty string, you would prefer Null or some other value to indicate none of the sourced Yes/No columns were `True`.

Answer (score 3):

You can use one query to update the `Status` in one shot via a nested `IIF`:

```
UPDATE NonConf AS N
SET N.Status = 
IIF (N.Closed, "Closed", 
IIF(N.Open, "Open",
IIF(N.OnHold,"OnHold","")))
```

Answer (score 2):

Something along these lines, one query for each status

```
UPDATE yourTable
SET status = 'Closed'
WHERE yourTable.Closed = 'Yes'
  AND status IS NOT NULL
```